# FIS-B lookahead for SUA Status

Tags: ads-b, notam, special-use-airspace

While reading over the recent FDC NOTAMs, I saw this interesting entry come up:

```
!FDC 0/6362 ZOA AIRSPACE SPECIAL NOTICE..THE FLT INFO SERVICES BCST
(FIS-B) SERVICE FOR OAKLAND /ZOA/ ARTCC AIRSPACE IS REDUCING ITS FIS-B
PRODUCT LOOKAHEAD RANGE TO 5NM FOR THE SPECIAL USE AIRSPACE (SUA
STATUS) PRODUCT. SUA STATUS INFO CONTINUES TO BE PROVIDED VIA THE
FIS-B NOTAM PRODUCT. ALL FIS-B PRODUCT FORMATS REMAIN UNCHANGED. THIS
UPDATE WILL OCCUR BTN 1400-1600 ON JUNE 11 2020. ANY OBSERVED ISSUES
SHOULD BE REPORTED VIA EMAIL TO [REDACTED] 2006111400-2008111600
```

Am I understanding this correctly to mean that SUA status sent over FIS-B will only cover a 5nm "hockey puck" around the aircraft?

That seems incredibly small, to the point where the data seems useless now — you'd have to be practically on top of a piece of special-use airspace before you'd get any information about it.

Does anyone the background behind this change is and what the actual impact is?